# Парсинг IOS чеков из Itunes на стороне сервера

Tags: ios, сервер, in-app-purchases

Есть приложение, которое имеет покупки в виде нескольких подписок и нескольких  inapp-ов. Я получаю чек покупок из sandbox-а в виде JSON:

```html
{
  "latest_receipt": "MIIUAgY....BHll6c=",
  "receipt": {
    "bundle_id": "com.app.my",
    "request_date_pst": "2019-09-23 01:18:54 America\/Los_Angeles",
    "app_item_id": 0,
    "original_purchase_date": "2013-08-01 07:00:00 Etc\/GMT",
    "request_date": "2019-09-23 08:18:54 Etc\/GMT",
    "original_application_version": "1.0",
    "download_id": 0,
    "receipt_creation_date_pst": "2019-09-20 06:30:07 America\/Los_Angeles",
    "receipt_creation_date": "2019-09-20 13:30:07 Etc\/GMT",
    "request_date_ms": "1569226734763",
    "receipt_creation_date_ms": "1568986207000",
    "version_external_identifier": 0,
    "original_purchase_date_pst": "2013-08-01 00:00:00 America\/Los_Angeles",
    "application_version": "1.2",
    "receipt_type": "ProductionSandbox",
    "in_app": [
      {
        "expires_date_pst": "2019-09-09 07:38:48 America\/Los_Angeles",
        "original_transaction_id": "100000056999999",
        "original_purchase_date_ms": "1568982954000",
        "original_purchase_date": "2019-09-20 12:35:54 Etc\/GMT",
        "is_in_intro_offer_period": "false",
        "web_order_line_item_id": "1000000046999999",
        "is_trial_period": "false",
        "purchase_date_ms": "1568039748000",
        "original_purchase_date_pst": "2019-09-20 05:35:54 America\/Los_Angeles",
        "purchase_date": "2019-09-09 14:35:48 Etc\/GMT",
        "expires_date": "2019-09-09 14:38:48 Etc\/GMT",
        "transaction_id": "100000057999998",
        "purchase_date_pst": "2019-09-09 07:35:48 America\/Los_Angeles",
        "expires_date_ms": "1568039928000",
        "product_id": "weekly",
        "quantity": "1"
      },
      {
        "expires_date_pst": "2019-09-09 07:41:48 America\/Los_Angeles",
        "original_transaction_id": "100000056999999",
        "original_purchase_date_ms": "1568982954000",
        "original_purchase_date": "2019-09-20 12:35:54 Etc\/GMT",
        "is_in_intro_offer_period": "false",
        "web_order_line_item_id": "1000000046999998",
        "is_trial_period": "false",
        "purchase_date_ms": "1568039928000",
        "original_purchase_date_pst": "2019-09-20 05:35:54 America\/Los_Angeles",
        "purchase_date": "2019-09-09 14:38:48 Etc\/GMT",
        "expires_date": "2019-09-09 14:41:48 Etc\/GMT",
        "transaction_id": "100000057999997",
        "purchase_date_pst": "2019-09-09 07:38:48 America\/Los_Angeles",
        "expires_date_ms": "1568040108000",
        "product_id": "weekly",
        "quantity": "1"
      },
      {
        "expires_date_pst": "2019-09-09 07:44:48 America\/Los_Angeles",
        "original_transaction_id": "100000056999999",
        "original_purchase_date_ms": "1568982954000",
        "original_purchase_date": "2019-09-20 12:35:54 Etc\/GMT",
        "is_in_intro_offer_period": "false",
        "web_order_line_item_id": "1000000046999997",
        "is_trial_period": "false",
        "purchase_date_ms": "1568040108000",
        "original_purchase_date_pst": "2019-09-20 05:35:54 America\/Los_Angeles",
        "purchase_date": "2019-09-09 14:41:48 Etc\/GMT",
        "expires_date": "2019-09-09 14:44:48 Etc\/GMT",
        "transaction_id": "100000057999996",
        "purchase_date_pst": "2019-09-09 07:41:48 America\/Los_Angeles",
        "expires_date_ms": "1568040288000",
        "product_id": "weekly",
        "quantity": "1"
      },
      ... (еще ~ 50 чеков)
    ],
    "original_purchase_date_ms": "1375340400000",
    "adam_id": 0
  },
  "status": 0,
  "pending_renewal_info": [
    {
      "auto_renew_product_id": "weekly",
      "expiration_intent": "1",
      "is_in_billing_retry_period": "0",
      "auto_renew_status": "0",
      "product_id": "weekly",
      "original_transaction_id": "100000056999999"
    }
  ],
  "latest_receipt_info": [
    {
      "original_transaction_id": "100000056999999",
      "original_purchase_date_ms": "1568986150000",
      "original_purchase_date": "2019-09-20 13:29:10 Etc\/GMT",
      "web_order_line_item_id": "1000000046999999",
      "purchase_date_ms": "1568986149000",
      "quantity": "1",
      "expires_date_ms": "1568986329000",
      "expires_date_pst": "2019-09-20 06:32:09 America\/Los_Angeles",
      "purchase_date": "2019-09-20 13:29:09 Etc\/GMT",
      "transaction_id": "100000057999998",
      "original_purchase_date_pst": "2019-09-20 06:29:10 America\/Los_Angeles",
      "subscription_group_identifier": "20541198",
      "product_id": "weekly",
      "expires_date": "2019-09-20 13:32:09 Etc\/GMT",
      "purchase_date_pst": "2019-09-20 06:29:09 America\/Los_Angeles",
      "is_trial_period": "false",
      "is_in_intro_offer_period": "false"
    }
  ],
  "environment": "Sandbox"
}
```

Какая **ПРАВИЛЬНАЯ** последовательность обработки данных в JSON-е на **Production** если пользователь возьмет сначала подписку, потом inapp, потом опять inapp, потом опять подписку и т.д.?
И как обработать grace-период и предоставить пользователю доступ во время его действия?

В текущей реализации я проверяю:

- поле *receipt.bundle_id* для валидации идентификатора приложения;
- прохожусь в цикле по массиву *latest_receipt_info* и обрабатываю поля:

  - поле *latest_receipt_info.original_transaction_id* для связи пользователя с покупиками в Itunes;
  - поле *latest_receipt_info.product_id* для определения идентификатора покупки **подписки или inapp-а**;
  - поле *latest_receipt_info.purchase_date_m*s для получения времени покупки **подписки или inapp-а**;
  - поле *latest_receipt_info.expires_date_ms* для получения времени окончания **только подписки**;
- прохожусь в цикле по массиву *pending_renewal_info* и обрабатываю поля:

  - поле *pending_renewal_info.product_id* для определения **только** идентификатора **подписки**;
  - поле *pending_renewal_info.auto_renew_status* для определения **только** статуса автопродления **подписки**;

и обновляю запись пользователя в БД.

Comment: Здравствуйте! У меня та же проблема. Как вы её решили и решили ли?

Comment: никак. оставил как есть пока. а грейс период обрабатываю в структуре pending_renewal_info в поле grace_period_expires_date_ms. если он больше текущего времени, то увеличивают время подписки на эту разницу.

Comment: спасибо! Попробую реализовать как у Вас.

Comment: @PavelLazarev вообще там всё плохо в отличие от Google Play. самая большая проблема в том, что от эпла не приходит ивент когда произошло списание денег при продлении подписки. а это основной кейс для аналитики. в своей реализации, при истечении подписки проверяю на этапе логина сохраненный в БД рецепт покупки. но это уже костыль... (p.s при реализации аналитики храните в БД идентификаторы типов ивентов и их даты для их сравнения при обработке уже последующих ивентов для избавления от дубликатов событий)

Comment: Спасибо! С Google Play мне еще только предстоит разбираться.

Comment: А какой идентификатор вы берете с ios устройства или только id транзакции?

Comment: @PavelLazarev для связи пользователя и покупок при первой транзакции (проверки чека от клиента) сохраняю "original_transaction_id" из подписок/инэпов. И потом при обработке ивента ищу пользователя в БД по этому айдишнику, который приходит в тексте ивента от сервера ITunes.